# Success Page is not appearing for Configurable - simple product

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, onepage-checkout, place-order

I'm using configurable product for my stores. i have multiple simple products under a configurable product. All functionalities is working except when i go and book a configurable simple product , the success page is not displayed when i hit place order ( but the order is placed in the admin panel, customer receive's the order confirmation message).

The scenario is

- When i order a simple product , the everything runs smoothly
- When i go to configurable product will select the color and size attribute for my product and checkouts. Till the **Place order** everything is fine, when i hit the **Place order** it just shoes "**Submitting Order Information**" GIF and nothing happens. The products are still in cart and i am not redirected to the success page.
  But the order is placed in the Backend admin panel

**Note:**

- Mb_string is enabled
- I have used **sales_quote_item_set_product** event to change the cart name and sku according to the configurable simple product in cart page

Below is the Observer i have written for the event

```
$event      = $observer->getEvent();
$quote_item = $event->getQuoteItem();
$storeId    = $quote_item->getStoreId();
$item       = $observer->getQuoteItem();
$product    = $observer->getProduct();
$sku        = $product->getSku();

$productDetails =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
$price      = $productDetails->getPrice();
$sprice     = $productDetails->getFinalPrice();

$item->setOriginalCustomPrice($sprice);
$item->setOriginalPrice($price);
//$item->getProduct()->setName($productDetails->getName());
```

Can someone please guide why im not getting the success page when the configurable product is ordered??

Comment: I think the problem is with the observer

Comment: @AthulVijayan could you please tell me what is the problem with the observer?

Comment: $event      = $observer->getEvent();
$quote_item = $event->getQuoteItem();
$storeId    = $quote_item->getStoreId(); these line are not needed i guess. Are you using any observer for checkout place after event?